# Getting the e-mail of someone who clicked on a button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Not sure if this is even possible, but my (admittedly basic and tertiary) Googling has turned up a lack of results.

Is it possible to fetch the e-mail address of someone who clicks a button?

I'm trying to make a check-out spreadsheet that has a few functionalities Google Forms does not offer: specifically, graying out options in a list while those options are unavailable. I don't want people ignoring an e-mail box that they're meant to type in, or using another person's email, but I can't figure out if there is or is not a way to get the e-mail of someone who clicks a button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its best to post a link to a sheet containing enough detail to allow people to better understand the question and be able to answer.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Apps Script `Session` class?

Comment: you can add a function to the button click event and get the active user by [currentUser=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()] and store it.

Comment: @tehhowch I _*sigh*_ hadn't managed to find that. Thanks.

Comment: @shabnambharmal Double thanks. My spreadsheet is nearly finished with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Shabnam got it.

[currentUser=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]

if you missed his comment.